# Wiki private vs public pages

Tags: php, mediawiki

Currently we have a private mediawiki installation by making

```
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
```

in LocalSettings.php, and have given public access to the home page:

```
    $wgWhitelistRead = array(
        "Main Page"
    );
```

## Question

I would like to know if it's possible to have a public wiki (for clients) with a private subset (for staff only). I'm aware of the fact that we could just have 2 separate installations, but ideally I want wiki.mydomain.com for all wiki content with a login request for private pages and edit actions.

Comment: Cloded? Really? I suspect if I was going to find an answer to this it would be some nifty trick in the code, wouldn't it? Take for example the code used in my question to achieve what I have so far.

Comment: You need to go back and 'tick' your correct answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357341/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily.

MediaWiki isn't built to have hidden sections. If it was a matter of a handful of pages, there are extensions that will allow you to secure them to a limited subset of users, but a second wiki is going to be the better bet really.

Comment: Yup, thanks. In my situation it might be the best route anyway. Besides the admins don't like this question :(

Comment: The question wasn't really an issue of programming.

Comment: Would have liked a code based solution, but went with the dual-wiki installation solution for now. The caveats here are double the maintenance when upgrading, installing extensions, maintaining users, etc.

Comment: You can set things up to have two wikis on a shared code base. I currently run 18 wikis using the exact same code base.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Check out on of the extensions on the [Category:Page specific user rights extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aPage_specific_user_rights_extensions) page. Also be aware of the [security issues](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Security_issues_with_authorization_extensions) with these types of extensions.

Comment: Oh, this answer was hiding under an advertisement. Interesting read - thank you. I'm pretty sure I'll find something in here...