# MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP field updates on every update

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

The best way to explain this problem is with an example.

### I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Result:

```
   id  |  data  |       created       |       updated
 (NULL)| (NULL) |       (NULL)        |       (NULL)
```

### Then I insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO example (
  `data`
) VALUES (
  'abc123'
)
```

Result:

```
  id  |  data  |       created       |       updated
   1  | abc123 | 2013-01-16 13:12:16 |       (NULL)
```

### And then I update

```
UPDATE example SET 
  `data` = 'def456',
  `updated` = NOW()
WHERE id = 1
```

Result:

```
  id  |  data  |       created       |       updated
   1  | def456 | 2013-01-16 13:16:24 | 2013-01-16 13:14:26
```

**The problem:** Notice how the `created` field also updates and has a slightly different time to correctly saved updated field. I have set up this example table and others similarly on the same database without this problem, so I'm completely baffled by it.

Comment: Just to clarify, notice how the `created` field ALSO updates. This is not working as documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely how the **problem table** table was accidentally created:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Perhaps someone used 3rd party software to create it?

An `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is going to destroy the create date. So to **solve the problem** use `ALTER TABLE` like so:

```
ALTER TABLE example CHANGE created created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

This will get rid of the unwanted overwrite of the `created` field on every update.

Answer (score 12):

`updated` needs to be: `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

So your `CREATE TABLE` would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This means that when you perform your `UPDATE` in the future, you won't need to pass in an update variable because MySQL will automatically update it for you :)

Comment: Ok, this is helping me. I was under the impression that MySQL would allow for only one `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. But using this knowledge, it is as if my `created` field was made with `NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Is there a way to check/change this without having to create the table again?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Quoting a line from the link in eggyal's answer [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html) : "It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column"

Comment: Yep, you can do: `ALTER TABLE example CHANGE updated updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` .. You need to use `ALTER TABLE` and `CHANGE` :)

Comment: Also you might want to take a look at the DEFAULT issue @Akahadaka posted about above, if it affects you. Perhaps having one of them DEFAULT to something else, and manually inserting it the first time round (I'd say `CREATED`).

Comment: I did thanks, just double-checked your answer now to see if I can mark is as the solution, but your query produces _Error Code : 1293 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause._ What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Hi I need help here,
Can I define a column in   `updated` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
so that I will update this field on a particular column update rather on whole row uodate?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, you should try asking this as a new question :)