# Insert data to table in php/mysql & automated insert date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**user** table:

```
User_ID
Username
Password
```

**campus** table:

```
Campus_ID
Campus_name
Campus_Addres
Campus_DateCreate
```

**edit campus** table

```
Edit_ID
Campus_DateEdit
User_ID
Campus_ID
```

I have 3 tables, when i edit data using form, I want in table edit campus, automated inserted `User_ID`, and `Campus_ID`, and the date automated inserted from current date. how do I do this with PHP syntax?

Comment: The poor english is no problem, but the fact you're flat out asking for people to do your work for you is.

Comment: You can do this with just MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14357410/485418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in php use

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

for datetime fields